# Android studio build failed-Could not find support-v4.jar

Tags: android

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.jar

But i have not used 24.0.0 version
Check the gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 14
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.XXX.app"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),        
 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
} }

dependencies {
provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23+' }
```

Comment: **compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23+'**
Gradle will automatically look for support library above version 23. Either use fullversion name like 23.0.2 (Just an example) to include specific support library version

Comment: **compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'** try this

Comment: Match the build tools and support Lib version .

Comment: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.0.0/support-v4-24.0.0.jar

Answer (score 1):

Just Delete the dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
```

I do not know why, but my project works.